# Bank Teller and his mother

Tags: situation

*I found this on 9GAG, albeit without an answer. I am really curious on what it is. It's copied word for word from 9GAG, hence the terrible english.*

---

You work at a bank and suddenly a gang of robbers shows up. One of them comes at you and tells you to give him all the money or he will shoot you. You tell the robber you don't have access to the deposit.

Suddenly the phone rings. The robbber tells you to answer the phone and don't say a word about this. You pick up the phone and it happens to be your mother.

After you talked to her, 15 minutes passed and the police arrived along with your mother and arrest the robbers.

What did you tell your mother at phone such that she understood you need help and the robbers couldn't notice?

Hints:

- The phone you used was a ring phone (not cell phone);
- You used a "little trick" when talking to phone with your mother;
- You didn't instruct your mother for this emergency, so she didn't know about a secret code for help.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I was struggling to find a suitable tag, hence why I went riddle

Comment: What is a "ring phone"?

Comment: @Andrey I assume it's a (corded) telephone, ie: not wireless

Comment: @Andrey I'm interpreting it as a land line phone. The OP copied it word for word from another site so deeper explanations might be a problem.

Comment: "Use this one '**[little trick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52924/30633)**' to get help quickly in any emergency!"

Comment: And I was thinking maybe they whistled somehow at the right frequencies to dial 911...

Comment: "Bank robbers hate this one simple trick you can do with a corded phone!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is:

> You ask your mother questions like "Is this an emergency? I'm busy at work" and say "I can come round later and help." but you use the mute button so all your mum hears is "emergency... work... help" etc. The actual words don't matter as long as you can filter in the message.

Comment: I've heard this before, I think it was in the game 'Mindtrap'